# ARDUINO PROGRAM

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, arduino-nano, bootloader

I have a project that consists in measuring the mass of an object with a strain gauge HX711.
so I found an interesting Arduino program and the editing that goes with it. 
but I have a problem, I manage to compile the program and then upload it but unfortunately my serial monitor still displays 0lbs.....
can you help me????

```
#include "HX711.h"

#define DOUT  3
#define CLK  2

HX711 scale;

float calibration_factor = -1242; //-7050 worked for my 440lb max scale setup

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("HX711 calibration sketch");
  Serial.println("Remove all weight from scale");
  Serial.println("After readings begin, place known weight on scale");
  Serial.println("Press + or a to increase calibration factor");
  Serial.println("Press - or z to decrease calibration factor");

  scale.begin(DOUT, CLK);
  scale.set_scale();
  scale.tare(); //Reset the scale to 0

  long zero_factor = scale.read_average(); //Get a baseline reading
  Serial.print("Zero factor: "); //This can be used to remove the need to tare the scale. Useful in permanent scale projects.
  Serial.println(zero_factor);
}

void loop() {

  scale.set_scale(calibration_factor); //Adjust to this calibration factor

  Serial.print("Reading: ");
  Serial.print(scale.get_units(), 1);
  Serial.print(" lbs"); //Change this to kg and re-adjust the calibration factor if you follow SI units like a sane person
  Serial.print(" calibration_factor: ");
  Serial.print(calibration_factor);
  Serial.println();

  if(Serial.available())
  {
    char temp = Serial.read();
    if(temp == '+' || temp == 'a')
      calibration_factor += 10;
    else if(temp == '-' || temp == 'z')
      calibration_factor -= 10;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Start by removing `1` from `Serial.print(scale.get_units(), 1);`

Comment: yes and @MikaelPatel

Comment: I removed the variable but now my serial monitor no longer displays a value? 
I would like him to give me the value of a weight of 1kg  .@MikaelPatel

Comment: To find the error you need to remove any possible source. Removing the number of decimal digits could help detect if you are measuring a small value. The next (or actual first) thing to check is the wiring and the power supply.

Comment: I have to check the power supply all is good so I will remove the decimal numbers but I don't see how this could help me? @MikaelPatel

Comment: even when trying to remove the decimal numbers I always stay at 0 …. @MikaelPatel

Comment: What is the calibration factor? And how did you calculate that? Or did you just copy that?

Comment: My guess (given that the device and wiring are working) is that the scaling/calibration factors are wrong for the weight interval you wish to measure. Please check these settings.

Comment: i calculate the calibration factor with another program that consiter to read only the calibration value! @Mikael Patel

Comment: Plese ..? @Mikael Patel